# java.util.Collection deserialization using jackson

Tags: json, collections, deserialization

I have a problem deserializing Collection. Please help me. Below there are 3 VO's and the first UpdateFiltersForQueueUserIdByVO  is getting passed to my REST method. If you see the inside vo's are old one's and 1.4 is used to compile them and they have generic Colleciton properties. json is unable to deserialize the Collection. How can we define mixin for FilterProfileVO, FilterVO. Thanks in advance.

// This is compiled in java 1.7, wrapper vo

```
public class UpdateFiltersForQueueUserIdByVO {
    private FilterProfileVO filterProfileVO;
}
```

// Below two vo's are getting compiled in java 1.4 and I can't change

```
public class FilterProfileVO extends ValueObject implements Serializable {

    // some other variables
    private Collection filterVOs;
}

public class FilterVO extends ValueObject{
    private Collection filterDetailsList;

    private Collection filterCodeValueColl;
}
```

Regarads,
GP

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after implementing below two mixin classes. Hope this helps someone.

```
public interface FilterProfileVOMixin {
    @JsonSerialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=FilterVO.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=FilterVO.class)
    public Collection getFilterVOs();
}

public interface FilterProfileVOMixin {
    @JsonSerialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=FilterVO.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=FilterVO.class)
    public Collection getFilterVOs();
}
```